# Bicep deploys a Linux App Service Plan regardless of Kind defined

Tags: azure, azure-bicep

I'm trying to deploy a windows app service plan through a BICEP script.  It deploys successfully with no issues/warnings/error.  Even though I have the 'Kind:' set to windows it still results in a Linux App plan.  Below is my BICEP code.  New to BICEP but after reviewing several samples and testing different things, I simply cannot get it to deploy a windows ASP.  What am I doing wrong?  Thanks in advance.

```
resource appServicePlan 'Microsoft.Web/serverfarms@2022-03-01' = {
  name: appServicePlanName
  location: location
  kind: 'windows'
  tags: tagValues
  properties: {
    reserved: true
  } 
  sku:  {
    name: sku
    tier: skucode
  }
}
```

location is EastUS   /   SKU is P1V2   /   SKUCODE is PremiumV2

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`reserved` should be `false`. I know, it's the most asinine and misdocumented thing. The 'kind' property seems to have no effect.

Comment: Holy snickeys!  That fixed it.  You are correct in that it is the most inane thing I've seen in a while!  Thank you kindly!!!!

Comment: It is "documented", not in the regular docs, but here: https://azure.github.io/AppService/2021/08/31/Kind-property-overview.html